# Analyzing For Loop Running Times?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, big-o, code-analysis

I was going through some practice problems and having a hard time understanding how to analyze the running times of these for loop functions (please have a look at the attached image)? It's question 1.4.6. Could someone please go through it step by step for me through the entire thing?

Link to image of textbook question I'm referring to (1.4.6): http://tinypic.com/r/2qapzir/8

Comment: You might consider taking the time to write the code in your question. External links offsite is discouraged as it makes the question become useless to future readers when the link dies. Especially given that image is just a picture of 10 or so lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example can help clarify Big-O notation and algorithm efficiency

[Quora: Big-O Notation explained by Gayle McDowell](http://qr.ae/S0cTW)

For the case of 1.4.6 a, the outer loop occurs with O(log n) and the inner loop occurs a menial number of times compared to that so the entire function would be O(log N).